# Jquery send result of SUM to div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to:
Get value from select, sum with other values, and place it inside a span.

Can I send the result of a value to a div/span without having to submit with a button? Is that possible?

please look at my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/groseler/3mq1ye1y/

HTML

```js
$(function () {
  $("#field16-1").change(function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    var comEx = "150";
    var youngDriver = "100"; 
    var resultSum = parseInt(val, 10) + parseInt(comEx, 10) + parseInt(youngDriver, 10);
     
  });
  $("#result").html(resultSum);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="field16-1">
  <option value="">Please select...</option>
  <option value="120">120</option>
  <option value="230">230</option>
  <option value="260">260</option>
 </select>
 <div>
 Result should appear here --->  <span id="result" ></span></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works after a bit change. You have only some typo. You need to add the `$("#result").html(resultSum)` into the `change` callback.

You don't need to submit anything. Submit is for the forms and after submitting the data almost always go to the server side code

```js
$(function () {  
  $("#field16-1").change(function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    var comEx = "150";
    var youngDriver = "100"; 
    var resultSum = parseInt(val, 10) + parseInt(comEx, 10) + parseInt(youngDriver, 10);
     $("#result").html(resultSum);
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="field16-1">
  <option value="">Please select...</option>
  <option value="120">120</option>
  <option value="230">230</option>
  <option value="260">260</option>
 </select>
 <div>
<span id="result" ></span></div>
```

Comment: @groseler Be a bit attentive :). Your code is working

Comment: You right, I have to be. Already too many hours in front the pc... Thank you one more time ;)

Answer (score 1):

Put  `$("#result").html(resultSum);` inside the function

```
$(function () {
  $("#field16-1").change(function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    var comEx = "150";
    var youngDriver = "100"; 
    var resultSum = parseInt(val, 10) + parseInt(comEx, 10) + parseInt(youngDriver, 10);
      $("#result").html(resultSum);
  });

});
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/3mq1ye1y/7/)

Answer (score 1):

The mistake you have done is that you put `$("#result").html(resultSum);` this outside the change event of dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

Move `$("#result").html(resultSum);` statement to within `.change()` so the the sum can be changed every time the value of the `select` element changes.

```js
$(function () {
  $("#field16-1").change(function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    var comEx = "150";
    var youngDriver = "100"; 
    var resultSum = parseInt(val, 10) + parseInt(comEx, 10) + parseInt(youngDriver, 10);
    $("#result").html(resultSum);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="field16-1">
  <option value="">Please select...</option>
  <option value="120">120</option>
  <option value="230">230</option>
  <option value="260">260</option>
 </select>
 <div>
 Result should appear here --->  <span id="result" ></span></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your time! I've already used the @SurenSrapyan answer.